# Alternatives of "contains" in Hive

Tags: hive, hql

I need to write a hive query in which the filter would be on the text of a field. Need to do something like where text_field contains ("pattern1" and "pattern2") or ("pattern3" and "pattern4")

I understand that we can use "like" multiple times, but I was hoping for a better alternative.

How else can it be done in Hive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `rlike`

TRUE if any (possibly empty) substring of A matches the Java regular expression B, otherwise FALSE. For example, 'foobar' RLIKE 'foo' evaluates to TRUE and so does 'foobar' RLIKE '^f.*r$'.

```
WHERE (mycolumn rlike 'pattern1' AND mycolumn rlike 'pattern2') 
OR (mycolumn rlike 'pattern3' AND mycolumn rlike 'pattern4')
```